# how to call output filename from scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

```
scrapy crawl test -o test123.csv
```

How can I call the Output filename from code i.e I would like to use the filename inputed in terminal in `spider_closed` function

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_closed)
def spider_closed(self):
    #read test123.csv (whatever the filename is)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `self.settings.attributes["FEED_URI"].value` in your spider to get output file name.

Comment: This does not work for me. Has the settings field change?

Comment: @kiril What is your scrapy version?

Comment: I am using Scrapy 2.5.1