# How to get the name of output file in scrapy spider's code?

Tags: scrapy

I need to process the output jl file after FULL scraping. What is the best way to do it from scrapy?

Now I do this:
1.Export to jl.

2.Converting to csv. (before convert all fields must be known to write headers.)

3.How to access the output filename from the spider class or class instance?

Comment: It looks like the object that holds the output file name as supplied by `-o` is not available to the `scrapy.Spider` plugin instances.  There's no way to get the object without changing the framework code itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047023/how-to-call-output-filename-from-scrapy